# Javascript regexObj.exec() says TypeError: pattern.exec is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

I want to extract image name from img tag with regex in **javascript**. My problem is that `console.log()` throws Exception:`TypeError: pattern.exec is not a function`.

**JS:**

```
$("label.btn-danger").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).parents("label").find("img").attr("src");
    var pattern = "/\/([A-Z0-9_-]{1,}\.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg))/ig";
    var result = pattern.exec(src)
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Remove the quotes, now you just have a string ?

Comment: `var pattern = /\/([A-Z0-9_-]{1,}\.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg))/ig;`

Comment: thanks, 1 more Q: this returns an array with 2 indexes?

Comment: Yes `[0]` element will be full matched input and `[1]` will be first matched group.

Comment: @adeneo, I can't extract the image name with result[1]. what should I do?

Comment: @anubhava , I can't extract the image name with result[1]. what should I do?

Comment: Then your regex doesn't match

Comment: Try changing `.attr("src")` to `prop("src")` and see what happens

Comment: @adeneo, Oh I forgot the ig part.thanks adeneo.

Answer (score 9):

```
var pattern = "/\/([A-Z0-9_-]{1,}\.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg))/ig";
```

Creates a string. A string has no method `exec`. You meant a `RegExp` literal:

```
var pattern = /\/([A-Z0-9_-]{1,}\.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg))/ig;
```

I suppose you might as wel use the `RegExp.test` method here, if all you need is confirmation that `src` complies to the given pattern:

```
var result = /\/([A-Z0-9_-]{1,}\.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg))/ig.test(src);
```

If you need a *matched* value, use `RegExp.match`:

```
var result = src.match(/\/([A-Z0-9_-]{1,}\.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg))/ig);
// let src be '../images/someimage.png'
// then result[0] = '/someimage.png'
```

Comment: I can't extract the image name with result[1]. what should I do?