# Why is Postman giving the error “TypeError: e.exec is not a function”

Tags: api, postman

I am trying to check if a string exists with

```
pm.expect(jsonData[0]["name"]).to.match('abagnale');
```

but I am getting

```
 TypeError: e.exec is not a function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript regexObj.exec() says TypeError: pattern.exec is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300616/javascript-regexobj-exec-says-typeerror-pattern-exec-is-not-a-function)

Comment: +1 hmmm, sorta but not what I wanted.  To explain: I want other users in the same situation to find help with this question and answer.  If a future user encounter this issue, the fact they are using postman an also the error message being e.exec instead of pattern.exec makes we doubt they would find this answer if they are in the same situation as posed above by me.  I could be 100% wrong as always.

Comment: Yes, other people finding help is the whole point of this. That's why marking as duplicate exists, rather than just closing and deleting - to leave signposts. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/. It doesn't matter if you're using Postman, which I'd guess is using Chai https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_match, "exec is not a function" in the context of regular expressions means you're not using a proper RegExp.

Comment: ah great point, ty. Now I wonder if i can vote my own as duplictae.

Comment: Yes I can and I did

Answer (score 6):

## Use a regex expression instead of a string

The error message is a little generic but in this case it can be fixed by using a regex

```
to.match(/abagnale/)
```

instead of a string

```
to.match('abagnale')
```

Comment: If you want to store the regex in the iteration data **JSON** file to match request results against it, store it as `{"myRegex": "abagnale"}` i.e. **without the forward slashes**, and access it as `new RegExp(pm.iterationData.get("myRegex"))`